# wordpress plugin readme.txt file interoperation of short code parameters

Tags: wordpress

I setup a WordPress plugin with a readme.txt file.

When I want to explain to this file how to use short code I simply do this :

[sagenda-wp view="calendar"]

However on the wordpress website it's interpreted like this :

[sagenda-wp view=“calendar“]

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/sagenda/

If a plugin user's copy-paste this short code it won't work. How can I correct this? There's no info on this on the official readme.txt example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in backticks to indicate it's code.

```
`[sagenda-wp view="calendar"]`
```

readme.txt files are parsed as [Markdown](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-your-readme-txt-works/#markdown)